# find total number of sold items per saleperson per shop within specific date range

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find total number of sold items per saleperson per shop withing a datetime range

The saleperson can be moved from one shop to another shop ( as all shops owned by a single person).

sale person can be mapped to n number of shops but at current moment he should be assigned to only one shop

take for example 'John' with sale_person_id = 1 worked in the shop_id = 1 for the period from  '2015-06-01 08:00:00' to '2015-06-01 13:00:00' but now he is working in the shop_id = 2 and he is still working there as his end_working_date is NULL

the output should be as :

```
sale_person_login_id    shop_name   count(*)
John                    Shop1             2
John                    Shop2             3
David                   Shop2             1
Jenna                   Shop3             1
```

here is the sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a8d2e/3

because during the period '2015-06-01 08:00' AND '2015-06-01 18:00'
John worked for 2 shops which are shop1 and shop2 , he sold 2 items when he was working in shop1 and he sold 3 items when he is in shop2

but the problem is that am getting the output as

```
sale_person_login_id    shop_name   count(*)
    John    Shop1   5
    John    Shop2   5
    David   Shop2   1
    Jenna   Shop3   1
```

Here is the query I am using

```
select sale_person.sale_person_login_id, shop.shop_name ,count(*) from sale 
join sale_person on 
sale.sale_person_id = sale_person.sale_person_id 
join sale_person_shop 
on sale_person_shop.sale_person_id = sale.sale_person_id 
join shop on shop.shop_id = sale_person_shop.shop_id 
WHERE sale.sale_date BETWEEN '2015-06-01 08:00' AND '2015-06-01 18:00'
GROUP BY sale_person.sale_person_login_id, shop.shop_name ;
```

Comment: And the problem is – ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this - although I'm not quite sure of the relationship between a 'sale' and an 'item'...

```
SELECT u.login_id 
     , s.shop_name
     , COUNT(l.sale_id) total_sales
  FROM user u
  JOIN user_shop us
    ON us.user_id = u.user_id
  JOIN shop s
    ON s.shop_id= us.shop_id
  JOIN sale l
    ON l.user_id = us.user_id
   AND l.sale_date BETWEEN us.start_working_date AND COALESCE(us.end_working_date,CURDATE())
 WHERE l.sale_date BETWEEN '2015-06-01 08:00:00' AND '2015-06-01 18:00:00'
 GROUP
    BY u.login_id
     , s.shop_name;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0cc87/20

Comment: thanks alot it works like a charm. I have edited my post and explained in details in the first post  you are kindly requested to view it .

Comment: Strawberry : I 'm not quite sure of the relationship between a 'sale' and an 'item'... please guide me if my tables design are not correct

Comment: Well, what happens if someone goes into a shop and instead of buying one apple decides to buy two apples, or one apple and one pear, or two apples and one pear. How do you store that? Now you have (potentially) one 'sale' with two (or perhaps three) 'items'.

Comment: @Stawberry : Strawberry : Thanks for your point. but :
1. I have already corrected the post(check the corrected post) , here the user indicates the sale_person , 
2. My aim of the post was to find the  total number of sold items/sales per saleperson per shop within a datetime range taking into considaration that user(sale_person) might move from one shop to another.
3. In my post i did not take consideration about the client and how many items will purchase or how many sales will make , because i was not concentrating in such point ,
I just wanted to concentrate in a single point in my post.

Answer (score 1):

Your query isn't relating a `sale` to a `shop`. That is, your query doesn't know which `shop` made a `sale`, so it's matching the `sale` to each row from `user_shop`.

Also, it's 2015 already... time to ditch the old-school comma syntax for the join operation (use the `JOIN` keyword), and move the join predicates to an `ON` clause.

```
 SELECT u.login_id
      , shop.shop_name
      , COUNT(*)
   FROM sale s
   JOIN user u
     ON u.user_id = s.user_id
   JOIN shop
     ON shop.shop_id = s.shop_id    -- this condition is missing from your query
   JOIN user_shop us
     ON us.shop_id = shop.shop_id
    AND us.user_id = u.user_id 
  WHERE s.sale_date BETWEEN '2015-06-01 08:00' AND '2015-06-01 18:00'
  GROUP BY s.user_id, shop.shop_name
```

Actually, I don't think the `user_shop` table needs to be involved in the query, assuming that `(user_id,shop_id)` is unique, and the purpose isn't to restrict some rows from `sale` being returned. The `user_shop` table could be omitted from the query:

```
 SELECT u.login_id
      , shop.shop_name
      , COUNT(*)
   FROM sale s
   JOIN user u
     ON u.user_id = s.user_id
   JOIN shop
     ON shop.shop_id = s.shop_id    -- this condition is missing from your query
  WHERE s.sale_date BETWEEN '2015-06-01 08:00' AND '2015-06-01 18:00'
  GROUP BY s.user_id, shop.shop_name
```

A `sale` is made to(by?) a `user`, and a `sale` is made at(by?) a `shop`.

But a `user` can have `sale`s at(by) more than one `shop`. Which is why the original query is returning inflated counts.

Comment: spencer7593 , thanks for your reply , your query does not work as shop_id does not exist in sale table . one more thing is that user is not a client , user indicates a saleperson . a saleperson(user) can work in any of the shops taking into consideration there are columns indicating the start_working_date and end_working_date of each user(saleperson) in a shop , in case the end_working_date is NULL , it means that the user(saleperson) is currently working in this shop .